# A multidimensional ELO rating with rock paper scissors playing styles: how to estimate

Tags: estimation, algorithms, games, elo

Consider the following latent variable model for a potential [Elo rating with additional player type](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557688/elo-rating-with-additional-player-type).

Each player has a performance level $r$ and a playing type $\theta$. Assume that a game between two players can be modelled as follows

- Compute the difference in playing styles $$d_1 = \frac{\theta_1 - \theta_2}{2 \pi} \text{ modulo 1} \\d_2 = \frac{\theta_2 - \theta_1}{2 \pi} \text{ modulo 1}\\$$
- Draw two random variables from a normal distribution $$X_1 = N(r_1+f(d_1),1) \\ X_2 = N(r_2+f(d_2),1)$$ where in the example here $f(d) = 300(1-d)^4d^2$
- The player with the largest number wins.

The $r$ plays a role of a traditional ELO rating. The $\theta$ has an adjusting effect on the probability of outcomes. When an opponent is $1/3$ clockwise from you, then you have an advantage, when an opponent is $1/3$ counter-clockwise from you, then you have a disadvantage.

Below is an example of a simulation for 25 players, playing a round-robin tournament where each player sees another player 20 times (each player has 480 games).

[image: example]

In the image you can see the effect of the playing style. The scissor in the top with a score of 228 has an above average performance $r$, but is scoring lower than several rocks in the bottom with lower $r$. This is because the rocks encounter many scissors where they have an advantage, but the scissors encounter not so many papers.

---

Question: Say we have a matrix of results from players' games, can we estimate the underlying latent variables $r$ and $\theta$? (Where the $\theta$ has of course a free degree of freedom due to symmetry and we can only recover the relative $\theta$ values)

R code for generating example data:

```
set.seed(1)

### generate some players
### with random statistics
n = 25
r = rgamma(n,100,10)
angle = runif(n,0,360)


### function for outcome of a single game
game = function(x1,t1,x2,t2) {
    angle1 = ((t1-t2) %% 360)/360
    angle2 = ((t2-t1) %% 360)/360
    performance1 = rnorm(1,x1)+300*(1-angle1)^6*angle1^2
    performance2 = rnorm(1,x2)+300*(1-angle2)^6*angle2^2
    if (performance1 >= performance2) {
       return(1)
    } else {
       return(2)
    }
}

### play some games
M = matrix(rep(0,n*n),n)

for (i in 1:n) {
   for (j in 1:n) {
     if (i != j) {
       for (k in 1:10) {
           outcome = game(r[i],angle[i],r[j], angle[j]) 
           if(outcome == 1) {
              M[i,j] = M[i,j] +1
           } else {
              M[j,i] = M[j,i] +1
           }
       } 
     }
   }
}


M[1:5,1:5]
```

The first 5 entries in the table will look like

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0   15    0   19   10
[2,]    5    0    0   17   13
[3,]   20   20    0   19   20
[4,]    1    3    1    0    5
[5,]   10    7    0   15    0
```

Comment: +1 Interesting problem. But what is your rationale for your choice of $f(d)$?  https://doi.org/10.1006/anbe.1998.0755 does something similar but predicts intransitivity from known covariates rather than latent variables (so that the model can be fitted as a simple glm).

Comment: @JarleTufto it is just a random function such that there is an effect that the best and worst opponents are at 1/3 rotation. In a more advanced situation this function $f(d)$ can be more flexible and itself subject of the estimation. I was thinking of alternatives that could work but a linear model but hadn't an idea. I will look at your reference.

Comment: At the moment I am thinking of an algorithm that looks at similarities between different players which might allow to order the players according to play type. I know something similar is done is movies of a beating heart where the frame rate is similar or slower than the heart beat, and the movie is reconstructed by ordering frames that look alike. ([Virtual High-Framerate Microscopy Of The Beating Heart Via Sorting Of Still Images](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8759595))